# How to get just a string from room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I need to get a string from my room database and set it as text in a textview i'm using this code in my dao

```
    @Query("SELECT question, question_heat, question_gender FROM questions WHERE question_heat = :heat AND question_gender = :gender" +
            " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
    String getQuestion(int heat, int gender);
```

i just want to get a random question from my question database.I get this error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type String getQuestion(int heat, int gender);
```

in the build output says the error is in the query

i'm really new in room i was using sqlopenhelper for a while and i don't really know what to do here.

i found some codes in google but they were for lists of data and i want to get just a string.

Comment: I don't know much about what you are doing, but the query most likely returns an object as you are selecting 3 columns. You should get the string value of your column from the object. Maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getString(int)) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select only `question` column. Try this way:

```
@Query("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE question_heat = :heat AND question_gender = :gender ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
String getQuestion(int heat, int gender);
```

Answer (score 0):

You select 3 columns and expect to get a string?

I think you must do this :

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_heat = :heat AND question_gender = :gender" +
        " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
QuestionEntity question(int heat, int gender);
```

and then convert it manually in repository with

```
String result = question.getQuestion + question.getQuestionHeat + question.getQuestionGender ;
```